# Bootstrap hamburger menu does not show icon-bar when background is white

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap version 3.3.7. I have customized the `navbar` styles to make background white and text black and some other styles. Everything is working except the hamburger menu does not show `icon-bar`. I have tried setting the `icon-bar` style explicitly

```
.my-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
  color:black;
}
```

but still does not work. I see the `icon-bar` when i hover over it. But i dont see it when page loads

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gd6dwfu/9/)

What i am missing here?

To reproduce the issue and see the hamburger menu please make sure to decrease the size of output window

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.my-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 icon bars use a background-color, not color. Try changing the background-color instead of color.

```
.my-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
  background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the following

```
.my-navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gd6dwfu/19/)